# How to get the amount of free space with Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.3.16 and would like to found out how much free space there is with Postgres

How to get the amount of free space with Postgresql?

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746680/1120863

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as free space in PostgreSQL: you only have free space available on the disk PostgreSQL is using to store its data. In PostgreSQL, you can find out the [Disk Usage](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage) of your tables etc.

For free disk space you need to see the output of system command [`df`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df). For security reasons you can't call these commands directly from PostgreSQL, but you may write an intermediate [untrusted PL/Python function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) for that.

Notice that the space available may also be limited by a quota affecting the user running PostgreSQL server. See [29.2. Disk Full Failure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/disk-full.html).